# Working with APIs in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api

This seems naive to ask, but seriously I have not seen a resource which explains how to work with an API. The basics. More specifically the procedure to start-up with an API.

There are loads of things in the docs. But how to get it working with an RoR app. Like what variables to put in the db, in the attr-accessible. Or is it even required.

Then parsing it in models. Managing from the controllers and displaying/calling in the view. Dont get me wrong, I do know about RoR, I have made apps, but with API, seems confusing. Need to know all the basics.

Is there any resource which teaches to work with an API. 
For my scenario, I want to work with a [travel API](http://www.wego.com/api/flights/docs). What should be the first procedure(after getting the API key).

Comment: You want to learn about working with creating an api in rails?

Comment: @uDaY working with API. The thing is it was easy to get started with rails. lots of tutorials telling step-by-step. but with API, cant figure out. Where to start? What to initialize from the console-is it all the variables from the doc or not? Those little stuff.

Answer (score 3):

How you work with an API is largely defined by how that API exposes itself, and what libraries of code you have to deal with it.

Many APIs are presented as HTTP endpoints that you can use `CURL`, `OpenURI`, `HTTParty` or something like that to consume the resource, or deal with the data sent to you, often as `JSON` or `XML`.

Here is a list of some of the more popular Ruby HTTP API client libraries at the [Ruby-Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients).

Pick one of these and write some code that gets an endpoint of that API, then use that data to do whatever you need. Treat the API somewhat like a database.

Codeschool has a cool course that you can start with and do the first few levels for free here:

[Surviving APIs with Rails](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/surviving-apis-with-rails)

Answer (score 2):

First, before choosing to work with an API or not, I highly suggest to try to work with REST API since these kind usually adhere to the same structure (there is even a book on REST API) and then you know what to expect.

Lets take a fictional Movie DB REST API example

so REST API is all about resources. Every movie can be created read, updating or deleted (CRUD).

so you know that you have these commands in your disposal - if you want to get a movie in your app you would use the read command that the api supplies. It usually looks like GET /movie/13 (HTTP GET request)

so in your app you would have to insert that line whereever you want it (perhaps in some panel where the user search for a movie and you access the movie DB to get the details of it

so you would have a

```
def movie_panel
  #some stuff

@movie = MovieDB::get(movie_name)
end
```

so now you have the movie.. now what? parsing it is indeed annoying. luckly most API have gems you can use so they did the parsing for you. Here I used the fake gem MovieDB but if there is no gem you need to query the api yourself, which in this case I advise you to build your own gem, or atleast have a module with some classes and method to make life easier for you. something like

```
module MovieDB

 class Movie

  attr_accesor :name, :year, etc...

 def initialize(movie_params)
  #initizalize the movie attributes from a given movie params
  @name = movie_params["name"]
  etc..
 end

end
end
```

so in this case you would have your own API wrapper to use. So once you are given the movie params from the external API you can do MovieDB::Movie.new(movie_params) and that will create a movie object that has method (that you need to write) for the functionality that you need in your code.

Inside that module you can handle everything about that API and abstract all that from the core of your app.

so to sum up -

REST API - easy, predictable, managable
non/rest api - make sure there is proper documentation
use what the api gives you as a resource, and ask yourself questions - what do I want from the API? what will I do with the resources (such as a movie, or a facebook page, or a tweet)? Does the API docs say its capable of doing what you want to do with the resource?

as documentation goes, you need to read it to understand what to do. No all docs are clear and not everything is clear on the first reading because you don't know where to start. So start at the beginning - why do you want to API? What does the API promise to do? You need to authenticate? Is there a tutorial? Has someone already made a gem for the API?

take some famous API's and not-so famous API as an example.

Facebook Graph API is very well documented. You know exactly what you get from each command and what to expect. You don't need to write it yourself, since Koala gem have you covered. On the other hand of the API rainbow, lies a Pinterest API, which you might wonder what's it for.. No one knows, because its barely useable, you need to get access to it, and even then its very limited. So if you want to plung in to the Pinterest API, make sure you understand what it gives you and what it doesn't (hint - it doesn't). That's true for every API where it has good docs or bad docs.

Good luck and might I suggest to read http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028468.do and maybe this as well - https://github.com/interagent/http-api-design

Update with the actual API

ok so the api http://www.wego.com/api/flights/docs you wanted is documented quite well

the first thing it says is to get the API rate check

GET http://www.wego.com/api/flights/usage.html?format=json&apiKey=testAPIKey

so right here you can begin to structure your code. You need to save the apiKey somewhere and have a url prefilled with http://www.wego.com/api/flights/usage.html and the parameters are the format and the apiKey

you can create a helper method that does that.

```
def check_rate(format, apiKey)
...
end
```

inside you will need to send a request and get the response and parse it something like

```
    uri = URI.parse(@url)
    https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
    req.body = ["format=" + @format, "apiKey=" + @apikey]
    res = https.request(req)
```

and that takes you forward one step. Take the result and parse it. Best in this case is to create a class for this kind of response and add methods such as rate_ok? and such. Basically a Class for each response and instantiate a class per response. The constructor of the class would parse the response and expose whatever attributes you need

Comment: whoa.that was elaborate! I will try to figure out the rest of the set up. the thing is, even though i know about hw rails works, can figure out to work with APIs. Like where to initialize the token, how to send them, what all parameters to initiate  from the console for the db(everything from the doc or not) for the API, all those small stuff. thnx though. And +1 for those links.

Comment: if you are talking about token and such, that means you aren't using a prepared API wrapper, and you need to write the module on your own. I would suggest to create a class for the connection and handle actions through there. Checkout the Koala gem which is a wrapper for the facebook api. Also, try to start small, write a class that just authenticates, and add on it. Jumping in on a massive api is complicated

Comment: I was looking to using this [API](http://www.wego.com/api/flights/docs). Just cant understand making it work with a rails app. So as you said first i will try with the Twitter API, then hopefully i may understand what all to do while working with an API(wat all to declare, initialize frm console using the doc or not, etc) just like there are a bunch of tutorials explaining step-by-step getting started to create a rails app. One day i will be a pro.

Comment: ok, i'll edit the answer to help you more

Comment: Hey i guess i figured out. No need to define variables through cmd prompt. Just create wrapper and use the API. Now I would want to learn how to code a wrapper for POST and other methods and also include API keys and setting customs headers. Do point a resource which you always refer while working with API. Thanks.

Comment: Can you ans this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304831/rails-working-with-api