# Rails working with API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I am beginner in working with API. I'm trying to work with the [Forecast API](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2). I don't want to use its [official wrapper](https://github.com/darkskyapp/forecast-ruby), because first I like to study and learn.

```
class Forecast
  include HTTParty

  base_uri "api.forecast.io/forecast/#{@api_key}/#{@latitude},#{@longitude}"

  def initialize(api_key,latitude,longitude)
     self.api_key = api_key
     self.latitude = latitude
     self.longitude = longitude
  end


end
```

Now what should be the next step after initialization. I've tried to understand using the `httparty` gem examples, but cant figure out what exactly to do.

Could you help me to fix it & point related resources with APIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not use httparty gem when working with APIs instead i use [typhoeus gem](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) which allow making parallel http requests and therefore enable concurrency but i believe the example below will also work if you use httparty.
I am going to use a simple example to show how i work with APIs. Let's say you are trying to communicate with a JSON api service to fetch a list of products.

The url of the service endpoint is `http://path/to/products.json`

in your application, you can have a `products_controller.rb` with an `index` action that looks like this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   # make a http request to the api to fetch the products in json format
    hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.hydra
    get_products = Typhoeus::Request.new('http://path/to/products.json')
    get_products.on_complete do |response|
      products = MultipleProducts.from_json(response.body)
      @products = products.products
    end
    hydra.queue get_products
    hydra.run
  end
end
```

Let's say that the http request to `http://path/to/products.json` returns the following json

```
{"products" [{"id": 1,
  "name": "First product",
  "description": "Description",
  "price": "25.99"}, {"id": 2,
  "name": "Second product",
  "description": "Description",
  "price": "5.99"}]
```

This json can be wrapped in a class with a name like, `multiple_products.rb` Which looks like this:

```
class MultipleProducts
  attr_reader :products 
  def initialize(attributes)
    @products = attributes[:products]
  end
  def self.from_json(json_string)
    parsed = JSON.parse(json_string)
    products = parsed['products'].map do |product|
      Product.new(product)
    end
    new(products: products)
  end
end
```

You can then use [ActiveModel](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) to create a product model like this:

```
class Product
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  ATTRIBUTES =  [:id, :name, :description, :price]
  attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES
  validates_presence_of :id, :name, :price

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    self.attributes = attributes
  end

  def attributes
    ATTRIBUTES.inject(ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new) do |result, key|
      result[key] = read_attribute_for_validation(key)
      result
    end
  end

 def attributes= (attrs)
   attrs.each_pair {|k, v| send("#{k}=", v)}
 end

 def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
   send(key)
 end
end
```

In your `app/views/products/index.html`, you can have:

```
<h1>Products Listing</h1>
 <ul>
   <% @products.each do |product| %>
     <li>Name: <%= product.name %> Price: <%= product.price %> </li>
   <% end %>
 </ul>
```

This will list all the products fetched from the api.
This is just but a simple example and there is much more involved when working with APIs. I would recommend you read [Service-Oriented Design with Ruby and Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321659368) for more details.

Comment: WhoOa..!That was complex. I guess i got to learn a lot to develop with API. Need to find a simple way to understand all those libraries. But thnx a lot for referring the book.